# What is the encode(<columnName>, 'escape') PostgreSQL equivalent in java?

Tags: java, string, postgresql

I have a bytea column stored in Postgresql db.

ColumnName:test

```
Ex:  \x61736461640061736461736400
```

When I use encode(test,'escape') in my select query i get something like this.

```
Ex: asdad\000asdasd\000
```

But How to do it If want to do encode-escape in Java? 
i.e If i have

`String str = \x61736461640061736461736400`

how to get  `asdad\000asdasd\000` as array of strings ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want an array of strings or do you want `asdad\000asdasd\000`?  Are you working with a byte array or an actual String?

**String to byte array (if working with a String)**

```
String str = "\x61736461640061736461736400"
str = str.substring(2); //get rid of \x
byte [] bytes = new byte[str.length()/2];
for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  String numberStr = str.substring(i*2,i*2+2);
  int numberInt = Integer.parseInt(numberStr);
  bytes[i] = (byte) numberInt;
}
```

**byte array to String ArrayList**

```
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
int startIndex = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
  if(bytes[i] == 0) {
    if(startIndex > i) {
      byte [] stringBytes = new byte[i - startIndex];
      for(int j = startIndex; j < i; j++) {
        stringBytes[j-startIndex] = bytes[j];
      }
      result.add(new String(stringBytes, "US-ASCII"));
    }
    startIndex = i+1;
  }
}
```

**byte array to octal escaped String**

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("000");
StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for(byte b : bytes) {
  if(b > 0) {
    char c = (char) b;
    resultBuilder.append(c);
  } else {
    int bInt = b & 0xFF;
    String octal = Integer.toString(bInt, 8);
    int numPadZeroesNeeded = 3 - octal.length();
    resultBuilder.append('\');
    for(int i = 0; i < numPadZeroesNeeded; i++) {
      resultBuilder.append('0');
    }
    resultBuilder.append(octal);
  }
}
```