# What is the encode(<columnName>, 'escape') PostgreSQL equivalent in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql

In the same vein as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20421882/what-is-the-encodecolumnname-escape-postgresql-equivalent-in-java), what is the equivalent in `SQL Server` to the following `Postgres` statement?

```
select encode(some_field, 'escape') from only some_table
```

Comment: For non-Posties, can you show sample input and expected ouput?

Comment: In case someone wonders, [ref](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-string.html): "Encode binary data into a textual representation. Supported formats are: base64, hex, escape. escape converts zero bytes and high-bit-set bytes to octal sequences (\nnn) and doubles backslashes."

Comment: T-SQL is renowned for how little string manipulation it supports. They've only just added UTF-8 support to the 2019 version of SQL Server. It doesn't have anything like `encode`. It has some minimal conversion functionality via `CONVERT` but nothing extensive.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Am I chasing a lost cause?

Comment: @Gareth why do you want this in the first place? You can store binary data in varbinary columns and Unicode data in `nvarchar` columns. These can be retrieved easily through OLEDB or ODBC. You can use a few tricks to Base64 encode a binary value but `escape` is a rather unusual way to encode binary data.

Comment: @Gareth `escape` will be *very* inefficient compared to Base64 unless the data is mostly ASCII characters. Are you trying to store/retrieve text? Why not use Unicode? If you really want to work with binary data, encoding would prevent you from storing large values or use streaming to read/write to `varbinary(max)` (blob) fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you were told already, SQL-Server is not the best with such issues.

The most important advise to avoid such issues is: Use the appropriate data type to store your values. Storing binary data as a HEX-string is running against this *best practice*. But there are some workarounds:

I use the HEX-string taken from the linked question:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100)='0x61736461640061736461736400';
```

--here I use dynamically created SQL to get the HEX-string as a *real binary*:

```
DECLARE @convBin VARBINARY(MAX);
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'SELECT @bin=' + @str;
EXEC sp_executeSql @cmd
                  ,N'@bin VARBINARY(MAX) OUTPUT'
                  ,@bin=@convBin OUTPUT;
```

--This *real binary* can be converted to a `VARCHAR(MAX)`.
--Be aware, that in this case the input contains `00` as this is an array.
--It is possible to split the input at the `00`s, but this is going to far...

```
SELECT @convBin AS HexStringAsRealBinary
      ,CAST(@convBin AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS CastedToString; --You will see the first "asda" only
```

--If your HEX-string is not longer than 10 bytes there is an undocumented function:
--You'll see, that the final `AA` is cut away, while a shorter string would be filled with zeros.

```
SELECT sys.fn_cdc_hexstrtobin('0x00112233445566778899AA') 
SELECT CAST(sys.fn_cdc_hexstrtobin(@str) AS VARCHAR(100));
```

### UPDATE: An inlinable approach

The following recursive CTE will read the HEX-string character by character.
Furthermore it will group the result and return two rows in this case.
This solution is very specific to the given input.

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100)='0x61736461640061736461736400';

WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS position
          ,1 AS GroupingKey
          ,SUBSTRING(@str,3,2) AS HEXCode
          ,CHAR(SUBSTRING(sys.fn_cdc_hexstrtobin('0x' + SUBSTRING(@str,3,2)),1,1)) AS TheLetter
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.position+1
          ,r.GroupingKey + CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@str,2+(r.position)*2+1,2)='00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
          ,SUBSTRING(@str,2+(r.position)*2+1,2)
          ,CHAR(SUBSTRING(sys.fn_cdc_hexstrtobin('0x' + SUBSTRING(@str,2+(r.position)*2+1,2)),1,1)) AS TheLetter
    FROM recCTE r
    WHERE position<LEN(@str)/2
)
SELECT r.GroupingKey
      ,(
        SELECT x.TheLetter AS [*]
        FROM recCTE x
        WHERE x.GroupingKey=r.GroupingKey
          AND x.HEXCode<>'00' 
          AND LEN(x.HEXCode)>0
        ORDER BY x.position
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
       ).value('.','varchar(max)')
FROM recCTE r
GROUP BY r.GroupingKey;
```

The result

```
1   asdad
2   asdasd
```

Hint: Starting with SQL Server 2017 [there is `STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), which would reduce the final `SELECT`...

Comment: Thank you for your response, the CTE was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

If you need this functionality, it's going to be up to you to implement it. Assuming you just need the `escape` variant, you can try to implement it as a T-SQL UDF. But pulling strings apart, working character by character and building up a new string just isn't a T-SQL strength. You'd be looking at a `WHILE` loop to count over the length of the input byte length, `SUBSTRING` to extract the individual bytes, and `CHAR` to directly convert the bytes that don't need to be octal encoded.<sup>1</sup>

If you're going to start down this route (and especially if you want to support the other formats), I'd be looking at using the [CLR support in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/introduction-to-sql-server-clr-integration), to create the function in a .NET language (C# usually preferred) and use the richer string manipulation functionality there.

Both of the above assume that what you're really wanting is to replicate the `escape` format of `encode`. If you just want "take this binary data and give me a safe string to represent it", just use [`CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#binary-styles) to get the binary hex encoded.

---

<sup>1</sup>Here's my attempt at it. I'd suggest a *lot* of testing and tweaking before you use it in anger:

```
create function Postgresql_encode_escape (@input varbinary(max))
returns varchar(max)
as
begin
    declare @i int
    declare @len int
    declare @out varchar(max)
    declare @chr int

    select @i = 1, @out = '',@len = DATALENGTH(@input)
    while @i <= @len
    begin
        set @chr = SUBSTRING(@input,@i,1)
        if @chr > 31 and @chr < 128
        begin
            set @out = @out + CHAR(@chr)
        end
        else
        begin
            set @out = @out + '\' +
             RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(varchar(3),
                (@chr / 64)*100 +
                ((@chr / 8)%8)*10 +
                (@chr % 8))
             ,3)
        end
        set @i = @i + 1
    end

    return @out
end
```